# Moq Async Callback Fails with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tdd, nunit, moq

I'm trying to workout if it is something I am doing wrong, or its an issue in moq or NUnit. I am calling a soap endpoint and my service reference is generating both sync and async methods.  The call I am making, looks something like:

```
public async Task DoThisAsync(idnameobject myobj, int id)
{
    await ws.DoSomethingAsync(myobj, id);
}
```

I am setting up my moq to return the callback, so I can interegate the parameters I have called the web service with. My test looks something like:

```
var callback = new idnameobject();    

wsMock
.SetUp(w => w.DoSomethingAsync(It.IsAny<idnameobject>(), It.IsAny<int>())
.Callback<idnameobject, int>((obj, id) => callback = obj);

await myservice.DoThisAsync(myobj, id);

Assert.That(callback.Id, Is.EqualTo(myobj.Id));
```

At this point, I get a null reference exception when calling my method, which doesn't contain any information in the stack trace. All I have is `Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll` in the output.

The bit that is strange, is that it does not fail if I setup the callback from the synchronous method and change my method to call that.

It also does not fail if I call an async method that only has one parameter.

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know as I don't want to change my method because of our tests, but ideally I want my test to ensure I am calling the web service correctly.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You are mocking `ws.DoSomethingAsync()` but aren't setting it up to return anything. The `DoThisAsync()` method will fail because it will try to await null. You can fix this by changing your set up code to

```
wsMock.SetUp(w => w.DoSomethingAsync(It.IsAny<idnameobject>(), It.IsAny<int>())
    .Callback<idnameobject, int>((obj, id) => callback = obj)
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(0));
```

If you are using .NET 4.6 or above you can replace `Task.FromResult(0)` with `Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: Great explanation and fixed my problem. Wish I could mark it as the answer for you.

Comment: Sorry, this did answer my question, just a little slow to mark it as such

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  Makes perfect sense and saved us from what could have been a lot more debugging / just giving up on that test case completely.  :P